# Embedding a static UITableViewController in the header of a dynamic UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I want to display a `tableview` with a static part followed by a dynamic part below it. Following SO's advice, I have done the following:

- Create a dynamic `UITableViewController A`
- As the header view of the first `UITableViewController`, use a container view embedding the static `UITableViewController B`

It works, but the header view embedding `B` desperately keeps its default height of 44 points, which is obviously not what I want.

In `A`'s `prepareForSegue`: I correctly get my `UITableViewController` as destination vc, but its `preferredcontentsize` is (0,0). The container view has no constraints and I cannot seem to add any in the `Storyboard`. If I inspect the destination vc's `tableView`, I see that its size is (600,73), probably meaning it hasn't been laid out yet.

How do I set the correct height for my embedded view?

[image: storyboard with embed segue]

Comment: Thanks Honk, Rohit, jtbandes for the editing, and Wain for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table view (controller) doesn't use autolayout for the size of the header. When the header view is set it has a particular size and that size will be maintained. At the moment your header view is added from the storyboard so it will never change size.

You need to layout your static table view content, or calculate the size it requires, and then add a suitably sized container view as the header. Any time the size needs to change you need to remove the old header, resize, and then add the new header.